# Private registration of “.co” domains, is it possible?

Tags: domains, private-registration

I've registered a lot of domains in the past and have always usually purchased the additional service to make them have private whois info (e.g. domains by proxy)

Today I registered two new ".co" domains from GoDaddy. I'm now trying to make these private registrations but it doesn't look like its possible.

Its it possible to make ".co" domains have private whois info?

Answer (score 1):

It's completely possible to change your whois info after registration, as long as your domain is unlocked. Any decent registrar will allow you to unlock and change your registration info to private if you want.

Though you probably should have just gone with a different registrar that doesn't charge you extra to not spread your personal info all over the internet.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that making a domain private afterwards will not prevent others from finding the original registration information. Sites like domaintools.com allow anyone to look up the domain history of most domains.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth reading this: http://www.metafilter.com/43557/Blogging-unanonymously

domain by proxy isn't as private as you might think.

Answer (score 1):

Nate,

I have a private .co (brandboom.co) and I had registered the domain at http://internetbs.net recently. Their website looks extremely crappy like it was created 10 years ago, but they've been superb for my domain registrations since my decision to leave GoDaddy. The user interface also needs work, but everything you need to connect the domain name to a host IP is all there. Also, there still might be a coupon floating around so that the private registration is free. I fully recommend them and if you need further evidence, do a search on http://www.webhostingtalk.com/ -- Nothing but good reviews.

Comment: I'll amend my answer by saying that http://internetbs.net did not renew my domain automatically even though it was scheduled to do so. I hadn't noticed until about 2 months after the fact because it was a parked domain, but they stated because I got to them past their grace period, I would have to pay something like $75 to reinstate it. They basically blamed me for their mistake, so I won't be using them again.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the .co domains in Private Registration. I guess it's a domain registry
thing. Godaddy and 1and1 doesn't allow that, and I believe all other registrars doesn't allow that as well. But you can always set a alternative reg-c information in your contact details if you do not want to disclose your personal contact information. WHOIS database will update every 24 hours.  Cheers.. ;)